# Flexbox: Only want to match the beginning of list items

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest, jquery-flexbox

I am using the Flexbox jQuery control.  I want to configure it to only match characters at the beginning of the string, so when the user types `u`, I want Flexbox to suggest ***U**ganda* and ***U**nited States*, but not *Ar**u**ba*.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to set the `matchAny` configuration option to `false`.

(This option was introduced in FlexBox 0.9.5, but is not documented)

Comment: Dude! You are awesome. I have wasted a lot of time, but didn't find anything related to `matchAny`. Its working like a charm. Thank you!